# Make an Array Reactive (Observable)

Tags: javascript, array, observer-pattern

I have written a simple JavaScript function to make an array reactive (i.e. observable). Is there anything I could improve? What the code does is take an array, a callback and a `this` value as arguments, then whenever the array gets updated or a value gets added to it, it runs the callback with the specified `this` value. It works similar to the obsolete `Array.observe()`.

```
function arrayObserve(array, callback, thisArg){
    var result = [];
    result.push.apply(result, array);
    function getterAndSetter() {
        if (Array.isArray(array))
            var currentArray = result;
        else
            var currentArray = Object.keys(result);
        console.log(result);
        currentArray.forEach( function(prop){
            if (Array.isArray(result))
                var currentProp = result.lastIndexOf(prop);
            else
                var currentProp = prop;

            Object.defineProperty(array, currentProp, {
                configurable: true,
                enumerable: true,
                set: function(val) {
                    result[currentProp] = val;
                    callback.call(thisArg, result);
                },
                get: function() {
                    return result[currentProp];
                }
            });
            //}
            if (typeof result[currentProp] == 'object') {
                arrayObserve(result[currentProp], callback, result);
            }
        });
    }
    getterAndSetter();
    ['pop','push','reverse','shift','unshift','splice','sort','map','filter'].forEach( function(method){
        Object.defineProperty(array, method, {
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            value: function () {
                var noReturnMethods = ['push', 'pop', 'reverse', 'shift', 'unshift'];
                if (noReturnMethods.indexOf(method) > -1) {
                    Array.prototype[method].apply(result, arguments);
                } else {
                    var results = Array.prototype[method].apply(result, arguments);
                    result = results;
                }
                callback.call(thisArg, result);
                getterAndSetter();
                return result;
            }
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this block:

> ```
> if (typeof result[currentProp] == 'object') {
>     arrayObserve(result[currentProp], callback, result);
> }
> ```

It appears that the code is handling nested arrays. Is that supposed to work with nested objects (A.K.A. associative arrays)? If not, then perhaps it would be better to use `Array.isArray()` like the start of `getterAndSetter()`.

---

The `if`-`else` logic within `getterAndSetter()` doesn't put the statements in a block (i.e. in curly brackets - `{` and `}`), whereas the `if`-`else` logic within the `value` function *does* put the statements in blocks. For the sake of readability (especially for others) it is best to be consistent with curly brackets style.

---

In the `else` block of the value function, when a return method is called:

> ```
> var results = Array.prototype[method].apply(result, arguments);
> result = results;
> ```

is `results` used to avoid side-effects of the method (e.g. splice)? If not, then there isn't really a need to use `results` - just re-assign `result` with the return value from calling `apply` on the method.

---

Perhaps you are already aware of this, but if I add a new element to an array using bracket notation after `arrayObserve` has already been called with the array as the first parameter, then the callback is not called - should that be the case?

```
var arr = [3, 5, [1]];
arrayObserve(arr, console.log.bind(null,'callback - arguments:'));
arr[3] = 4;
```

#### Edit

One other thing to consider is using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) when creating `result`, *unless a shallow-copy won't work*. That could simplify the following first two lines of `arrayObserve()`:

> ```
> var result = [];
> result.push.apply(result, array);
> ```

To this:

```
var result = Array.from(array);
```

If a deep-copy is desired, then the trusty JSON methods can be utilized:

```
var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it helped me the most, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some minor nit-picks about your code.

> ```
> Object.defineProperty(array, method, {
>     configurable: false,
>     enumerable: false,
>     writable: true,
>     value: function () {
>         // ...
> ```

Here, `configurable` and `enumerable` default to `false` anyway. You needn't set them explicitly.

> ```
> if (noReturnMethods.indexOf(method) > -1) {
>     Array.prototype[method].apply(result, arguments);
> }
> ```

With ES6, you can write the `if` condition more concisely as `noReturnMethods.includes(method)`.

You could improve readability by storing `['pop','push','reverse','shift','unshift','splice','sort','map','filter']` in a variable. You could probably do

```
var noReturnMethods = ['push', 'pop', 'reverse', 'shift', 'unshift'];
var returnMethods = ['splice','sort','map','filter'];
var methods = [];
methods = methods.push.apply(noReturnMethods, returnMethods);
```

... to avoid duplication of the names of methods.

With ES6, you could do `methods = [...noReturnMethods, ...returnMethods]`.

Assuming your environment supports ES6, you should probably make use of arrow functions and the `let` and `const` keywords.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My environment doesn't necessarily support ES6, but will keep those in mind. If it did, I would probably use Proxies to achieve this.